# if $f$ and $g$ are smoothly homotopic, then they have some common regular value

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

I was reading Milnor's differential topology book. in page 24 when talking about homotopy class and mod 2 degree, there is an claim:

> Let $f,g:M\to N$ as smooth map between two smooth manifolds (where $M$
> is compact and $N$ is connected), we assume $f$ is smoothly homotopic to
> $g$, then there exists a regular value for both maps $f$ and $g$.

I can prove the following result,that is given map $f$ if it has a regular value $p$,then exist a map in the homotopy class that can be any regular value.

That is we know given $p$ there exsit a diffeomorphism $F$ which can change $p\in N$ to any $q\in N$ ,and $F$ smooth isotopy to identity maps(which is given by homogeneity lemma).

hence $f\cong f$(f smooth homotopy to itself) we also have $F\cong id$ hence $f\cong F\circ f$ now the RHS $F \circ f$  has regular value $q$

I don't know how to use Sard's theorem here to prove given $f,g$ exist common regular value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true for any two $f,g$. You do not need the fact that they are homotopic.

Let $M' = M + M$ be the disjoint union of two copies of $M$. Then $f, g$ induces a smooth map $\phi : M' \to N$ by taking $f$ on the first summand and $g$ on the second.

The set of regular values of $\phi$ is non-empty (it is dense in $N$). Any regular value of $\phi$ is a common regular value of $f,g$.

Comment: Can you provide some reference books that talk about those things?

Comment: How to defined $\phi : M' \to N$ is it defined as $\phi(x,y) = f(x) + g(y)$?

Comment: The disjoint union $M  + M$ is not $M \times M$, but can be identified with $M \times \{0,1\}$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology. Clearly it is a smooth manifold with the same dimension as $M$. We have $\phi(x,0) = f(x), \phi(x,1) = g(x)$. There are many textbooks on differential topology, but I doubt that you will find one which contains "everything".

Comment: can you provide a bit hint?I try to figure out the differentiation for $\phi$ that is $d\phi :T_pM \oplus \{0\} \to T_{\phi(p)}N$  what's the relation between $d\phi$ and $df,dg$ ?  By  the way can you provide some reference book?

Comment: The tangent space $T_{(p,i)}M'$ at $(p,i) \in M'$ can be naturally identified with $T_pM$. Doing so, we see that $T_{(p,0)} \phi : T_{(p,0)}M' \to T_{\phi(p,0)} N = T_{f(p)}N$ is nothing else than $T_pf : T_pM  \to T_{f(p)}N$ , similarly for $i=1$. A regular value of $\phi$ has the property that for all $y  \in \phi^{-1}(x)$  we have $T_y \phi$ nonsingular. This implies that for all $p$ with $(p,0) \in \phi^{-1}(x)$ (which means $p \in f^{-1}(x)$) we have $T_pf$ nonsingular, similarly for $g$.

Comment: Some books are Tu, An Introduction to Manifolds / Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds / Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds / tom Dieck, Differential Manifolds / Munkres, Analysis on Manifolds. There are many other, and you have to find out which you like.

Comment: thanks for your help